# Postgres Left Join ignores row if ManyToOne property is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-one

In Spring Boot i have the following query in a PostgreSQL database, to get data from ConfigElement table and set them to the new one ConfigurationReview table. It works properly as expected:

```
@Query(
          "SELECT new xx.xx.xx.dao.ConfigurationReview(r.id, MAX(ce.id) AS configElementId,"
        + " r.checkMethod, r.targetDate, r.endDate, r.sessionDate, SUM(CASE WHEN i.criticality ="
        + " 0 AND i.relation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majorFindings, SUM(CASE WHEN i.criticality"
        + " = 1 AND i.relation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS minorFindings, r.state) FROM"
        + " ConfigElement ce "
        + "LEFT JOIN ce.reviews r ON r.configElement.id = ce.id "
        + "LEFT JOIN r.criteria cr ON cr.review.id = r.id "
        + "LEFT JOIN cr.issues i ON i.criterion.id = cr.id "
        + "WHERE ce.id = :configurationId AND r.id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY r.id")
  Page<ConfigurationReview> findConfigurationReviews(
          @Param("configurationId") Long configurationId, Pageable pageable);
```

There was a need to add another property (r.milestone) with a ManyToOne relation, so i added it to the query:

```
@Query(
          "SELECT new xx.xx.xx.dao.ConfigurationReview(r.id, MAX(ce.id) AS configElementId,"
        + " r.checkMethod, r.targetDate, r.endDate, r.sessionDate, SUM(CASE WHEN i.criticality ="
        + " 0 AND i.relation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS majorFindings, SUM(CASE WHEN i.criticality"
        + " = 1 AND i.relation = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS minorFindings, r.state, r.milestone) FROM"
        + " ConfigElement ce "
        + "LEFT JOIN ce.reviews r ON r.configElement.id = ce.id "
        + "LEFT JOIN r.criteria cr ON cr.review.id = r.id "
        + "LEFT JOIN cr.issues i ON i.criterion.id = cr.id "
        + "WHERE ce.id = :configurationId AND r.id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY r.id")
  Page<ConfigurationReview> findConfigurationReviews(
          @Param("configurationId") Long configurationId, Pageable pageable);
```

Here is the milestone entry in ConfigurationReview dao:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_review_milestones_on_milestone_id"))
  private Milestone milestone;
```

With the above changes, it works properly if r.milestone is not null. But when the r.milestone is null, the complete row is ignored in left join.

As a result, if I have 2 r.milestones with data and 2 r.milestones without, the above query returns only two entries instead of four.

The problem appears only if r.milestone is null (because of the ManyToOne relation?). If another property is null, the row is returned properly.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Move r.id condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Hi, i moved the WHERE conditions to ON:
LEFT JOIN ce.reviews r ON r.configElement.id = ce.id AND ce.id = :configurationId AND r.id IS NOT NULL "
but the problem stil remains.

Comment: Is milestone a simple attribute or an entity. If it is an entity there will be an inner join between reviews and milestones. To avoid it, you need another left join to get milestone under another alias to use in the projection.

Comment: You can also set `show_sql=true` to see precisely the native sql request executed.